# Kotlin XML Parsing

Tags: javascript, java, xml, kotlin

I have been tasked with building a business logic library for a mobile application in Kotlin that I can include in either a Java project or Javascript project through cross-compilation.

My current issue is that the library needs to parse XML into data structures but any XML parsing libraries I can find are either dependent on JS or Java.

Is there any current implementation of an XML parser in pure Kotlin?
If not, what would be the best starting point for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I didn't succees in finding such parser. But I think that that's ok. I think you need 3 modules in your application:

1. Core module with crossplatform business-logics
2. Module with XML parsing logics for JS
3. Module with XML paring logics for Kotlin

Thing is Java ecosystem may use very effective approaches to handling data — InputStreams, SAX and so on. And of course all available parsers do this.

In JS you have to use simpler approaches with loading document fully into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, a pure Kotlin port of kXML is available at https://github.com/kobjects/ktxml

(Disclaimer: I wrote kXML and the Kotlin port)